# Most efficient way to find whether matching row exists in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

tableCollections: `collection INT INDEX NOT NULL, item VARCHAR INDEX NOT NULL` -- Contains items belonging to a collection. About 1,000 items per collection id.

tableData: `item VARCHAR INDEX NOT NULL, itemAttr1 VARCHAR, itemAttr2 VARCHAR` -- 
Contains all possible items and their data. About 10,000 items.

I want to select all items from tableData that are contained in a collection.

The three ways I know of doing this are either with a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM tableData
WHERE item IN (SELECT item from tableCollections WHERE collection = 3)
```

Or with a left join:

```
SELECT * FROM tableData
LEFT JOIN tableCollections USING (item)
WHERE tableCollections.collection = 3 AND tableCollections.item IS NOT NULL
```

Or with an inner join (via @Phate01):

```
SELECT * FROM tableData
INNER JOIN tableCollections USING (item)
WHERE tableCollections.collection = 3
```

Since this query will be executed every few seconds I want to go with the option that is the most efficient. Is anybody aware whether one of these might be better than the other or will they be optimized to the same thing anyway?

Comment: All 3 queries not equivalent to one another. They'll return different results. Have you tried them?

Comment: They were equivalent in the cases I tried, but I may have missed some edge cases. Why are you saying they are not equivalent?

Comment: The 2nd and the 3rd are equivalent if and only if the `tableCollections.item` column has no nulls.  The 1st and the 2nd are not equivalent because they show different number of columns as output.

Comment: It would help if you added the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output in the question (for both tables).

Comment: The columns are declared as NOT NULL, so they will not contain nulls. The output is also not really relevant, since my question is really about the efficiency of finding the rows in the first place. I agree that the create table statements would have made this clearer, but the real-life case is unfortunately much too complicated for this. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM tableData
INNER JOIN tableCollections USING (item)
WHERE tableCollections.collection = 3 AND tableCollections.item IS NOT NULL
```

As `LEFT JOIN` takes also the items not in the collection number 3, and then filters the data.

`INNER JOIN` takes only record that are in both tables, this way you handle less data

Comment: Good point! I will edit that into the first post. I guess MySQL should actually optimize the LEFT JOIN version to the same as this, but I'm not sure if that will work or not.

Comment: Actually you could also drop the `tableCollections.item IS NOT NULL` then, couldn't you?

Comment: If `tableCollections.item` is a `PRIMARY KEY` (as it should be) or anyway if you're sure that no rows have the item set to null then yes 'cause it can't be null

Comment: It's not (since multiple collections can contain the same item) but it is declared as `NOT NULL`.

Comment: You'll have no problem then. Another point that crossed my mind is that if you use `LEFT JOIN` make sure the left table to be the one with less data, cause it puts the whole left table in your resultset

Answer (score -1):

This one must be faster :-)

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableCollections
LEFT JOIN tableData
USING (item)
WHERE tableCollections.collection = 3 AND tableCollections.item IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hmm, why are you saying it must be faster?

Comment: Because the logic of data you want to get says tableCollection is smaller, and you need only records from both tables but you don't need records that does not exists in tableCollection, that means if you filter with WHERE before LEFT JOIN it will reduce number of records a lot.